# Need help placing HTML child element behind a parent element using CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like an HTML element to show up behind a fixed header element in HTML. (Think dropdown menu under a fixed header.) Problem is, the div element (which is a child of the header element) always displays on top for all permutations of z-index and position I've tried. Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wm3dk82x/4/

Read comments in the jsfiddle code. I've permuted position and z-index, but can't get it to work. HTML and CSS snippets follow:

```css
.header {
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;    /* must be fixed -- not an option to change this value */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 5;
}

.divinheader {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;   /* changed this for every option of position */
  padding-top: 50px;
  top: 0;
  left: 90%;
  width: 8%;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;      /* less than the z-index of parent  (2 < 5) */
}
```

```html
<div class="header">fixed
  <div class="divinheader">fixed1</div>
</div>
<div class="content">relative</div>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
```

Comment: Well, I got my solution this way. The answers mentioned in the question above just referenced standards that said it couldn't be done. (Thanks, John!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
<div class="header">fixed
  <div class="divinheader">fixed1</div>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="divinheader">fixed1</div>
<div class="header">fixed</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0t471c3w/